# Avoiding a NPE when checking JSON response using JsonPath and Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured, jsonpath

Given the following JSON:

```json
{
    "priceOne": 1034,
    "priceTwo": null,
    "priceThree": 7282,
}
```

...and the following Rest Assured method to get the `priceTwo` value and set to a specific value:

```
public void getPrice() {

    setPriceService();

    Response response =
            given().
                    spec(priceServiceRequestSpec)
    when().
            get("api/v1/prices/102934").
                    then().extract().response();

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(response.path("priceTwo").toString())) {
        vehicle.setPrice(response.path("priceTwo").toString());
        return true;
    } else {
         vehicle.setPrice("2000");
    }
}
```

...I am getting a NullPointerException when I expect the
`StringUtils.isNotEmpty` to handle this.  I expect this is down to the way I am using the `response.path` as a paramater.  What is a better way of achieving this?

Comment: If you are receiving this JSON object, you should never have an NPE. Are you sure "priceTwo" exists? If it doesn't, you will get the NPE on the .toString(), no on StringUtils.isNotEmpty().

Comment: @JoãoFarias thanks, I think this makes sense.  Problem is, I never know which price will be null, so I wanted a better way of doing a null check without lots of boilerplate try/catch NPE code.  Any of the prices can be null (not a string "null") and I need to set a value IF they are null

Comment: I think this is perhaps the right approach:
https://www.jvt.me/posts/2019/04/23/rest-assured-verify-field-not-set/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String response =RestAssured.get("https://praveendvd.free.beeceptor.com/test").
                        then().extract().response().asString();
    
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
       
int val = (jsonObj.isNull("priceTwo")) ? 2:jsonObj.get("priceTwo");
vehicle.setPrice(val);
```

you can directly pass without creating a variable also:

```
vehicle.setPrice((jsonObj.isNull("priceTwo")) ? 2:jsonObj.get("priceTwo"));
```

**use JsonObject has method and ternary operator java**

Comment: thanks for the answer - this looks the neatest solution yet the `jsonObj.has` always evaluates to true, because `priceTwo` key always exists, regardless of whether value is null, so the l/h side of `?` always gets run with the result:

org.json.JSONObject$Null cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$Null cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: @Steerpike use jsonObj.isNull("species") then , i thought you want to validate whether key exists or not

Comment: apologies, I probably wasn't clear.  I want to perform conditional logic IF a value is null.  So, I want to send a new Update RQ if any of the key values are null e.g. if `"priceTwo": null`

Comment: @Steerpike is updated answer

Comment: thank you for your help; appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Response response =RestAssured.get("https://praveendvd.free.beeceptor.com/test").
                    then().extract();

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(response.path("priceTwo").toString())) {
    vehicle.setPrice(response.path("priceTwo").toString());
    return true;
} else {
     vehicle.setPrice("2000");
}
```

You should creating a variable and also most probablity, you have a type casting problem that Response type to convert String for condition.

Answer (score 0):

Since the path returns a [reference type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type_and_reference_type) you can just use the construction like this:

```
if (response.path("priceTwo") instanceof Number) {
    vehicle.setPrice(response.path("priceTwo").toString());
    return true;
} else {
     vehicle.setPrice("2000");
}
```

**Below is the test:**

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Response response = RestAssured
                .get("https://60269516186b4a0017780505.mockapi.io/rest_assured_nulls");
        handleJson(response, "[0].priceOne");
        handleJson(response, "[0].priceTwo");
        handleJson(response, "asdfe");

    }

    private static void handleJson(Response response, String path){
        if (response.path(path) instanceof Number) {
            System.out.println("Valid number: " + response.path(path).toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid number so setting default value");
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
Valid number: 1034
Invalid number so setting default value
Invalid number so setting default value
```

for my [test endpoint](https://60269516186b4a0017780505.mockapi.io/rest_assured_nulls)

Comment: if response doesn't have priceTwo it will throw null point , that was the question i guess

Comment: No, it will not. `null instanceof Number` will return `false`

Comment: response.path("priceTwo") will through the error

Comment: response.path("asdasd") try this it will throw nullpoint

Comment: Not sure why we're talking about `response.path("asdasd")`. OP's issue is that `"priceTwo": null` causes `.toString()` be invoked against null reference because the value of the field is `null`. I'll check your examples as soon as get to my desktop.

Comment: even for null and key doesn't exists , it will thorugh the nullpointexception

Comment: Still can't follow you.. Can you check my update? I put the test where there are both field having null value and field that does not exist. Both are handled properly.

Comment: https://postmantest.free.beeceptor.com/test do a get to this endpoint and try to call response.path("priceTwo")

Comment: Just taken your URL and put it to my code. Everything is handled correctly..

Comment: Thank you you are correct the toString was causing the issue